# Library not found for -labc clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode8

I am adding a third party library in to my xcodeworkspace,but facing this issue.The example project code given by the vendor (3rd party) works fine but not in my project.

Please help me to solve this issue .Thanks in advance .

Comment: what issue you are getting?

Comment: library not found .but I have added the library in build phases

Comment: can you add stack report

Comment: what is stack report

Comment: I am integrating payment gateway using third party vendor trying to add .a lib file but facing this issue.

Comment: Call the app life cycle method of third party code with your xcodeworkspace life cycle method. Ex:- inside DidFinishlaunch method you should call the disfinishlaunch method of third party app

Comment: @ShubhamMishra but why can't I only add library?

Comment: if you have two different projects in one app then launching in one go will create two UIWindow which needs to be switched once app launches

Comment: No there is only one app I am integrating the library file and other header files to make it work in my project.